# How to Exchange Sorted Data as-is Through Feing Client

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, hashset, treeset, spring-cloud-feign

I am working on a system using micro-service architecture using Spring-Boot. I need one microservice to send sorted data to another microservice. I have used Set in DTO. When I directly call the first services end point it serves the data in sorted order. But when it goes through the Feing Client they are jumbled unpredictably.

I want them to be in the order as they are. I do not want to give second microservice the overhed of sorting those data since there is already a performance hit in that service.

Is there a way of overcome this issue?

Comment: Which class are you using for set ?

Comment: It is a field in DTO. I did not use any specific implementation of the set but the Set interface.

Comment: Ok, need to check serialization and de-serialization with feign client, but can you try by putting LinkedHashSet ?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati I'm already looking into it. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try that.